# drawString doesn't print

Tags: python, reportlab

I try to use [enter link description here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/08/12/reportlab-how-to-add-page-numbers/) this to generate page nums.

The most important part:

```
   class PageNumCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
        """
        http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546511-page-x-of-y-with-reportlab/
        http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576832/
        """
        #----------------------------------------------------------------------
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Constructor"""
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.pages = []

        #----------------------------------------------------------------------
        def showPage(self):
            """
            On a page break, add information to the list
            """
            self.pages.append(dict(self.__dict__))
            self._startPage()

        #----------------------------------------------------------------------
        def save(self):
            """
            Add the page number to each page (page x of y)
            """
            page_count = len(self.pages)

            for page in self.pages:
                self.__dict__.update(page)
                self.draw_page_number(page_count)
                super().showPage()

            super().save()

        #----------------------------------------------------------------------
        def draw_page_number(self, page_count):
            """
            Add the page number
            """
            self.line(10*mm, 78, 200*mm, 78)
            if (self._pageNumber % 2) == 0:
                self.drawString(15*mm, 15*mm, '{}'.format(self._pageNumber))
            else:
                self.drawRightString(195*mm, 15*mm, '{}'.format(self._pageNumber))

  class MyDocTemplate(SimpleDocTemplate):
        def __init__(self, filename, **kw):
            self.allowSplitting = 1
            super().__init__(filename, **kw)

            def setBackground(canvas, doc):
                color = PCMYKColor(5,3,0,8)
                canvas.setFillColor(color)
                canvas.rect(0,0,doc.width+doc.leftMargin+doc.rightMargin,doc.height+doc.topMargin+doc.bottomMargin, fill=True, stroke=False)


            #Two Columns
            frame1 = Frame(self.leftMargin, self.bottomMargin, self.width/2-6, self.height, id='col1')
            frame2 = Frame(self.leftMargin+self.width/2+6, self.bottomMargin, self.width/2-6, self.height, id='col2')
            frameT = Frame(self.leftMargin, self.bottomMargin, self.width, self.height, id='normal')

            frame1a = Frame(self.leftMargin, self.bottomMargin, self.width/2-6, self.height/2-6, id='col1a')
            frame2a = Frame(self.leftMargin+self.width/2+6, self.bottomMargin, self.width/2-6, self.height/2-6, id='col2a')
            frameTa = Frame(self.leftMargin, self.bottomMargin+self.height/2+6, self.width, self.height/2-6, id='normala')

            self.addPageTemplates([
                PageTemplate(id='OneCol',frames=frameT, onPage=setBackground),
                PageTemplate(id='TwoCol',frames=[frame1,frame2], onPage=setBackground),
                PageTemplate(id='OneAndTwoCol',frames=[frameTa,frame1a,frame2a], onPage=setBackground),
            ])

        def afterFlowable(self, flowable):
            "Registers TOC entries."

            if flowable.__class__.__name__ == 'Paragraph':
                text = flowable.getPlainText()
                style = flowable.style.name

                if style == 'TOCheading':
                    key = 'h2-%s' % self.seq.nextf('TOCheading')
                    self.canv.bookmarkPage(key)
                    self.notify('TOCEntry', (0, text, self.page, key))

    doc = MyDocTemplate(buffer,showBoundary=0, leftMargin=2*cm, rightMargin=2*cm, topMargin=2*cm, bottomMargin=2*cm)
    styles=getSampleStyleSheet()

    heading= ParagraphStyle('heading',
                           parent=styles['Heading2'],
                           fontName = 'LiberationSansBold',
                           textColor = PCMYKColor(98,46,0,84),
                           spaceAfter=5
                           )
```

And it works:

```
Story= []
Story.append(Paragraph("First Page", heading))
#Story.append(NextPageTemplate('OneCol'))
Story.append(PageBreak())

Story.append(Paragraph("Middle Page", heading))
#Story.append(NextPageTemplate('OneCol'))
Story.append(PageBreak())
Story.append(Paragraph("Last Page", heading))

#start the construction of the pdf
doc.multiBuild(Story, canvasmaker=PageNumCanvas)
```

But if I uncomment the NextPageTemplate line - page number disappears BUT LINE IS STILL VISIBLE....

Have no idea why NextpageTemplate vanish page number....

Comment: You're going to need to show us some more code, like the `addPageTemplates` call where you added 'OneCol', and the `Frame` definitions that fed into it.  I could not duplicate this.

Comment: @TimRoberts - I tried to reduce to single problem, but sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the fill color to that bluish gray when you draw the background, and leaving it there.  The "fill color" is what is used to draw strings, so your text IS being drawn, it's just being drawn in your background color.

Add

```
        self.setFillGray(0)
```

in your `draw_page_number` routine before drawing the text.  Or, perhaps do that in your `setBackground` function just before exiting, to restore the default.

Comment: You're absolutely right... canvas.SaveState() /canvas.RestoreState() do the job.....I should ask earlier....

Comment: That was going to be my 3rd suggestion... ;)